# MongoDB installations - Failed to download resource "c-ares"

Tags: mongodb, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install MongoDB on Mac using homebrew with the following steps:

1: brew tap mongodb/brew

2: brew install mongodb-community@5.0

[image]

This is the error that I'm getting after step 2.

Any suggestion on how to complete the installation?

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution or, better to say, understanding after days of troubleshooting this problem.
Homebrew cannot handle internet connections problems; hence if your internet is not stable, Homebrew will crash while trying to download and install any library.
Homebrew will write that some library is missing during the installation.
I tried to install the needed library separately, but it didn't work for me.
In the end, I tried a different internet connection that eventually worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).